# VBA Successive Class object reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a VBA project that can be used to calculate properties of gas flow through a duct system. The duct system consists of a number of Segments (a VBA class; clsSegment) stored in a Collection stored by the class clsSegments.

Each Segment has a Duct class (clsDuct) which consists of an Inlet and Outlet defined by the class clsDuctDim.

If I want Segment no. 2 Inlet Duct to inherit the properties of Segment no. 1 Outlet Duct I use:

```
set Segments(2).Duct.Inlet = Segments(1).Duct.Outlet
```

This works.

Likewise I can choose to use the inlet duct as outlet duct by:

```
set segments(2).Duct.Outlet = segments(2).Duct.Inlet
```

Now if I want Segment no. n+2 to do the same I write:

```
set Segments(3).Duct.Inlet = Segments(2).Duct.Outlet
set Segments(3).Duct.Outlet = Segments(3).Duct.Inlet
```

This causes Segment no 3 to actually point to Segment no. n. If I break the reference between Segments 2 and 1, Segment 3 still points to Segment 1. This is not what I want. I want that Segment 3 is pointing to Segment 2. I guess what I am trying to do is to point to a pointer, rather than point to the actual memory location where segment 1 data is stored.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do that in the VBA.  An easy workaround is to add a Copy or Clone method to your clsSegment Class.

> Segments(3).Copy Segments(2)

```
Sub Copy(segement As clsSegment)
    Me.Duct.Outlet = segement.Duct.Inlet
    Me.Duct.Inlet = segement.Duct.Outlet
End Sub
```

The can automate changes by adding custom events and setting references to parent object. I'm not sure how this would apply to your system but here is a simple notification system.

**clsSegment**

```
Enum DuctEvents
    deInletRemoved
    deOutletRemoved
End Enum

Public Sub DuctChanged(e As DuctEvents)
    'Do Something
End Sub
```

**Class clsDuctDim**

```
Public Event DuctRemoved()

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    RaiseEvent DuctRemoved
End Sub
```

**Class clsDuct**

```
Public parent As clsSegment
Private WithEvents Inlet As clsDuctDim
Private WithEvents Outlet As clsDuctDim

Private Sub Inlet_DuctRemoved()
    parent.DuctChanged (deInletRemoved)
End Sub

Private Sub Outlet_DuctRemoved()
    parent.DuctChanged (deOutletRemoved)
End Sub
```

I added an Enumeration to the clsSegment class to clean up the messaging.

Comment: OK, what I did was to write a house keeping sub in the Segments class that runs through all segments and set/break references to each other whenever a reference is set or broken. I need to call it manually though.

Comment: You'd lose all your values when the reference is broken, isn't that what you wanted to avoid?

Comment: I have a copy function as you mention where I take copy by value of the referenced values and store them in a temporary clsDuctDimension instance. Then I break the reference, and copy the values to Segment(2).Duct.Inlet or Outlet.